# VSCode "Import X could not be resolved" even though listed under `help('modules')`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm on day 1 of Python and trying to import `SciPy` into a project.  I installed it via `pip install` on ElementaryOS (an Ubuntu derivative).  I have verified it's existence via:

```
$ python
>>> help("modules")
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

> Import "scipy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

When searching for this error I found:

1. [Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10 Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486207/import-could-not-be-resolved-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-in-vs-cod) -- the accepted answers all pointed towards a project specific `.env` file.  I have no such project structure, nor does it make sense to me that one would be needed.
2. [A github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1271) -- this issue ends with "it just fixed itself"

When I run my program, I get no errors in console.  And looking up "Pylance" it appears to be a Microsoft product.  I suspect that VSCode is failing to lint correctly.  Potentially because `pip` installed something in a place it wasn't expecting.  This is my guess, but any help would be very much appreciated.

---

Edit:  Following through on the idea of missing paths, I found this post -- [How do I get into the environment VS Code is using for pylance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088670/how-do-i-get-into-the-environment-vs-code-is-using-for-pylance)

Having added the path to where my modules can be found has yielded no results, though I'm not sure if the formatting is correct.  Perhaps it needs glob syntax (eg path/**/*)

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue was indeed with `Pylance`.  It was missing an "additional path" to where `pip` had installed the projects I wanted to import.  To solve the issue:

First make sure you know the location of your import; you can find it with:

```
$ python
>>> import modulename
>>> print(modulename.__file__)
```

Then, once you know the location:

1. Open settings (ctrl + ,)
2. Search "pylance" or find it under "Extensions > Pylance"
3. Find the "Extra Paths" config item
4. Use "add item" to a add a path *to the parent folder of the module*.  It will not do any recursive tree searching

And you should be good to go!

For a further example, you can see the image above where I had added the path  `/home/seph/.local/lib/python2.7/` to no avail.  Updating it to `/home/seph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. To add extra notes for others, I was only having this issue with Jupyter Notebooks within VSCode. I was using a Kernel from a env I created with Anaconda. All packages installed through Conda in that env were working well EXCEPT the one package I installed via pip (openai). When I added the path to the openai module I installed using pip it resolved everything.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem in my setup as I create a virtual environment per project and install Jupyter there. Instead of a global setting change in the Pylance extension, I rather prefer to follow what states [its troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings).

Suppose your virtual environment is called `venv` and it is inside your project folder:

- Create a folder called `.vscode` at the root of your project folder, if it does not already exist. Don't forget the dot in front of the name.
- Create or edit the file `.vscode/settings.json` and include this tag:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./venv"]
}
```

- Note that the path to your virtual environment is relative to the root project folder, not the folder containing the `settings.json` file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. I just want to point out that (of course) I had to restart vscode.

Comment: it only worked when I set the full path of the site-packages: `./venv/Lib/site-packages`

Answer (score 4):

It works for me when I added my virtual environment path to the extra path of Pylance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Installing

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32
```

globally (outside python virtual env) solved my problem in vscode

Answer (score -2):

Some users report that restarting the system might help. It worked for me.