# import error message, even though import works

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, pylance

I am running a script in Visual Studio Code 2, for which I have the following import line `from module_name.blah.foo import bar`

The script works fine, but I get a "problem" message saying `Import "module_name.blah.foo" could not be resolved`.

If I hover above the line in the script, I get the message `Import "module_name.blah.foo" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)`

As the script works, this isn't hugely important, but I would like to get rid of the ever-present list of "problems" indicated for the script in the problems window and next to the filename, so I'd like to solve this if possible.

I saw [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322120/vscode-import-x-could-not-be-resolved-even-though-listed-under-helpmodules) that might help. However, when I tried the first step, `print(module_name.__file__)`, I get the error `NameError: name 'module_name' is not defined`

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Do you have the right python interpreter selected? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters

Comment: @ringo Sorry, I solved this myself and never put up a solution. This was actually exactly the issue. I found & specified the python interpreter path manually, using the path within the docker container, and the warnings went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this.

The solution is easy and may seem obvious, but for others like me who don't know where to look, here is what I did:

**(1) Find python used in docker container:**  I suspected I had the wrong python interpreter, but I didn't know where to find the python interpreter used within the docker container. What worked is I opened a terminal within Visual Studio Code 2 and, starting from root ("/"), searched until I found the python interpreter.

Alternatively, typing `which python` in the terminal also gave me the same answer.

**(2) Set interpreter path manually:** I then clicked on the button on the bottom bar of the VSCode2 window that specifies the python interpreter, and entered its path manually using the path I discovered within the docker container. (See official reference for setting VSCode2 python interpreter [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)).

Once I did this, the warnings went away.