# vscode/pylance auto-import incorrect root path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, vscode-python

Let's suppose that I have a project with this file structure:

```
project_dir
└── src
    ├── package1
    │   └── module1.py
    └── package2
        └── module2.py
```

When I want to use some class from module1 in some other module I type something like

```
class SomeNewClass(ClassFromModule1):  # here I press ctrl-space to make auto-import
    ...
```

When Pylance makes auto-import it always takes it starting from the root directory of the project, so I got this auto-import:

```
from src.package1.module1 import ClassFromModule1
```

The problem is that my working directory is **src** and I want to get

```
from package1.module1 import ClassFromModule1
```

Is there any way to fix root path of the auto-import Pylance feature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088670/how-do-i-get-into-the-environment-vs-code-is-using-for-pylance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if you import a module in `src`, it should look like the following (same effect as you want).

[image]

[image]

So please check if the following settings in vscode are modified: Open **Settings** and search for **Analysis: Auto Search Paths**.

[image]

**This item is enabled (checked) by default. If it was modified to be off, turn it back on.**

*Here are some examples:*

**Folder structure:**

```
Project_dir
├─ folderone
│  └─ package3
│     └─ moudle3.py  # --class C
├─ src
│  ├─ package1
│  │  └─ moudle1.py  # --class A
│  └─ package2
│     └─ moudle2.py  # --class B
└─ Test.py
```

- If you import the modules in the `src` folder (the above settings are enabled by default):

  ```
  # import code will not include `src` (like the picture shown above)
  from package1.moudle1 import A
  ```
- If the above features are turned off, the import code is as follows:

  [image]
- If importing modules under other folders: The import code will start from the first level folder under the current workspace.

  [image]

  [image]

***Note:*** vscode uses the currently open folder as the workspace. So which level of folder you open will also affect the code in the import part.

*The above example is to open the `Project_dir` folder as a workspace in vscode.*

If I put `Project_dir` in a new folder `ImpDemo` and open the `ImpDemo` folder in vscode. Then the code of the import part is like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My example was not very precise, in fact my working dir is something like "myproject", so Auto Search Paths does not working. But I have found another setting  **python.analysis.extraPaths**. Adding "myproject" into that setting helped me. Anyway thanks for the right direction of digging!

Comment: By the way, please describe your problem correctly when asking questions in the future, even as a minimal reproducible example, it should reproduce the problem you're having, not a different one. That way you don't make the problems that other people are trying to solve make no sense.

Comment: In my case it was happening just the **opposite**! It was omitting `src`, but I needed it to be included, so I **disabled the auto search** and provided the name of my project in the `extraPaths` just like @AntonM. said above.